# How to extract specific info under a specific class?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Having an `html` string like below,

```
...
<ul class="not-this-class" ...>
    ... <!-- some "<li> <a href.. > </a> </li>" here -->
</ul>

<ul class="yes-this-class" ...>
    <li>
        <a href="/some-text-1">some text 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/some-text-2">some text 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/some-text-3">some text 3</a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>

<ul class="not-this-class-either" ...>
    ... <!-- some "<li> <a href.. > </a> </li>" here -->
</ul>
```

I can extract the class named `yes-this-class` using the following code:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(responseString.ToString());
HtmlNode htmlNode =
    document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='yes-this-class']");
```

then, I do some string manipulation (*regular expression*) to extract the text below:

- some text 1
- some text 2
- some text 3

How can I extract the result just above, using **only** *HtmlAgilityPack* and **without** using *regular expression*? I tried something like below but it didn't work.

```
HtmlNodeCollection htmlNodes =
    document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='yes-this-class']/[@a='href']");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following XPath query:

```
//ul[@class='yes-this-class']/li//text()
```

Then run `Trim()` on each result to remove any leading and trailing whitespace around the string.